Can't edit block after Upgrade Magento CE 2.4.6-p3 -> 2.4.6-p8
I can't edit blocks after I upgraded my Magento installation on a testing instance from 2.4.6-p3 to 2.4.6-p8
What could be the reason? Any hints where I can start investigating? I already tried to search through the logs in ./var/log but no hints to the problem.
I am clueless right now.
I also tried:
bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
with no success.
That is how I updated the magento installation:
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento cron:remove
php bin/magento cron:run --group=consumers
# Check if any cron jobs are still running
while pgrep -f 'bin/magento queue' >/dev/null; do
  echo "Waiting for cron jobs to complete..."
  sleep 10
done

composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p8 --no-update --interactive-root-conflicts --force-root-updates
composer update

[ -d var/cache ] && rm -rf var/cache/*
[ -d var/page_cache ] && rm -rf var/page_cache/*
[ -d generated/code ] && rm -rf generated/code/*

php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
php bin/magento cron:install

php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:clean

After clicking "Save" it hangs here:

EDIT
I applied the patch (was this patch only for the commerce version, I am on the community edition).
Ran: bin/magento cache:flush && bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && bin/magento indexer:reindex
Console still shows the following error and the "Please wait..." spinner keeps showing:


Try to check the Browser Console to see if there is any error log.

Hi @KhoaTruongDinh, I applied the patch mentioned below and updated my question above to show the console.

Hi @KaiMechel just remove your vendor folder and reinstall the vendor using the composer install command might be this fixes your issue. for more reference check https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/39250#issuecomment-2519182816

@RutvikMonpara I am so happy, you can't imagine! Now I can save the block as expected!! Would you mind writing your solution again as an Answer to this question, so I can acceppt it as the solution for my problem?

In fact, on my testinstance, I rebuild from my backup (with the error) and after a simple bin/magento cache:flush the problem was also gone. Like in this comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/39250#issuecomment-2448340875
Such a strange behaviour, and Adobe does not seem to provide a fix in newer versions.

Just remove your vendor folder and reinstall the vendor using the composer install command might be this fixes your issue. for more reference check https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/39250#issuecomment-2519182816

Some more info for my specific case: The error was gone with this solution, thank you! But can come back. In that case a bin/magento cache:flush will help to make the save operation work again.

This is an official bug in Adobe Commerce.
To resolve the issue, please install the patch ACSD-60169_2.4.6-p6.patch. (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/39076)
You can download the patch from the following link:
https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/tree/d2e5320f0588419c3bb013ebfbe4c50c64139852/patches/os
Patch Name: ACSD-60169_2.4.6-p6.patch
EDIT:
After reviewing your updated question, error seems to be with your site headers. Please update as per your server like for nginx you have to update in this file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';


Hi @Grazitti-Dev , thanks for you nice structured answer, I could find all the information. I applied the patch - I edited my Question above to add screenshots and info after applying the patch. But the problem is still there.
